# What is noun expression of "create concept"

Tags: expressions

I'd like to mention **create of concepts** with more simple way like "**concept creation**".

Is it ok to write "**concept creation"** in a formal report?

If NO, could you please show me alternatives?

Unfortunately, "concept invention" can not be used because it is reserved as a proper noun. (There is a kind of research field called "concept invention".)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for when you say "concept creation" but maybe you are looking for "proof of concept"?

Comment: @Leo No. What I tend to mention is a kind of process where creating new product or service concept such as "new gadget shop for elder people who are interested in starting use smart phone".

Answer (score 1):

> **conceptualize**, v.  to form a concept of; *especially* :  to interpret conceptually
>
> - **conceptualization**

Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceptualize). There's also [Freedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conceptualisation).

Answer (score 1):

'Concept creation' is, in my opinion, quite acceptable in a formal report. However, if you really want to avoid it then 'ideate' or 'ideation' could be used. These words mean forming and relating ideas, and so I suppose it could be used to substitute for 'concept creation'.